# How to get length of an array in MySQL column?

Tags: mysql, arrays, mysql-json

I have an array in column Temp and I am trying to find the length of an array.
I tried `JSON_LENGTH` but it's not working.

So far I tried this

```
SELECT JSON_LENGTH(Temp)from tbl_name;
```

And got this

[image]

```
Id  Temp
1   ['53682', '66890', '53925', '54847']
2   ['53682', '66890', '53925', '54843','54890']
```

Expected Output:

```
Id  Temp                                             Count
1   ['53682', '66890', '53925', '54847']             4
2   ['53682', '66890', '53925', '54843','54890']     5
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working?" Does it give an error? If so, what is the error? Are you using an older version of MySQL that doesn't have JSON functions?

Comment: That isn't valid JSON, by the way (use of single-quotes where double-quotes are required in valid JSON). I suspect you aren't using the JSON data type, which would reject the data you show above.

Comment: @BillKarwin I tried SELECT JSON_LENGTH(Chance)from table_name; and I got null for all rows.

Comment: @BillKarwin I am using 8.0.23 version and I have JSON function.

Comment: I tested it using MySQL 8.0.23, and it works if you use double-quotes instead of single-quotes.

Comment: Can you paste the query I am trying but still getting error? I think I am doing something wrong. @BillKarwin

Comment: @sheel The question isn't whether you have JSON functions, it's whether you used the JSON datatype when creating the table. What does `SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name` say that datatype of the `Temp` column is?

Comment: Is the column named `Temp` or `Chance`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have two possibilities

1. the old fashion ways
2. Replace the ' with '

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `Id` INTEGER,
>   `Temp` VARCHAR(44)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`Id`, `Temp`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', "['53682', '66890', '53925', '54847']"),
>   ('2', "['53682', '66890', '53925', '54843','54890']");
> ```

> ```
> seLECT `Id`, `Temp`, CHAR_LENGTH (`Temp`) - CHAR_LENGTH (REPLACE(`Temp`,',','')) + 1  as cnt FROM table1
> ```
>
> ```
> Id | Temp                                         | cnt
> -: | :------------------------------------------- | --:
>  1 | ['53682', '66890', '53925', '54847']         |   4
>  2 | ['53682', '66890', '53925', '54843','54890'] |   5
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table2 (
>   `Id` INTEGER,
>   `Temp` VARCHAR(44)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table2
>   (`Id`, `Temp`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '["53682", "66890", "53925", "54847"]'),
>   ('2', '["53682", "66890", "53925", "54843","54890"]');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `Id`, `Temp`, JSON_LENGTH(`Temp`) AS cnt FROM table2
> ```
>
> ```
> Id | Temp                                         | cnt
> -: | :------------------------------------------- | --:
>  1 | ["53682", "66890", "53925", "54847"]         |   4
>  2 | ["53682", "66890", "53925", "54843","54890"] |   5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5659b1c409bb0967195594453c5bf09a)*